# Not so Isekai manga where the main character finds a portal while on a camping trip

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I have been looking for an manga (or something similar, I can't remember) where the main character found a portal to another world while out on a camping trip. He had a camera with him to record it. Later on he goes back through the portal with more equipment and stuff and he gets chased up a tree by a giant wolf, I think?

I do remember that later on he starts a fort or something with elfs or humans in the other world. He live streams it back to Earth. He also got some Earth tech to their world through the portal; including a truck full of weapons and food.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any characters or places?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://myanimelist.net/anime/52830/Isekai_de_Cheat_Skill_wo_Te_ni_Shita_Ore_wa_Genjitsu_Sekai_wo_mo_Musou_Suru__Level_Up_wa_Jinsei_wo_Kaeta - Main character does photography and goes camping at one point, but the portal is in his house

Comment: thank you for the welcome DavidW I do remember that I read this a year ago and that the main charter lured the wolf thru the portal back to earth to defeat it but he didn't kill it if that is any help. Valorum even though they sound similar the manga "I Got a Cheat Skill in Another World and Became Unrivaled in The Real World, Too" is not the one that I was looking for but thank you for the help. if it would help I do remember that some of it is in color but I don't remember much since I read this a year ago and I don't remember any of the names.

Comment: by "some of it is in color" do you mean that most of it is in black and white? Another question; do you remember about how many chapters of it you read?

Comment: How certain are you about the livestreaming? *Saikyou no Ossan Hunter Isekai e ~ Kondokoso Yukkuri Shizuka ni Kurashitai ~* has an older man fall into a hole while out on a picnic, and is taken to another world with elves. But he goes from one fantasy world to another - afaik, there's no internet or cameras in either world. Is there any chance you're mixing up multiple different series?

Comment: qazmlpok i cant remember on the color part but i did read more then 10 chapters. and no  it is not "Saikyou no Ossan Hunter Isekai e ~ Kondokoso Yukkuri Shizuka ni Kurashitai" because it was a fixed portal that the main character go thru and he can go back and forth thru the portal at a certain time of day I stoped reading when the portal  was starting to close for an extended period of time because of the winter I think? thank you for the help though I might start read the story that you said while looking for the manga that I am looking for.