# Looking for a novel camping isekai

Tags: story-identification, isekai

I'm looking for a novel where the protagonist can travel between dimensions through a portal, which he uses to make content to upload to his YouTube channel in the modern world. The portal closes and opens from time to time and he takes advantage of those moments to transport food and equipment to the other world. At a certain point in the story he decides to take his mother to that other world as well, and after some event the portal closes and he decides to stay in the other world to live. Some time later the portal opens again and upon returning to Earth he discovers that it has been invaded by a race of monsters and he takes on the task of saving as many people as he can and taking them to the other, more peaceful world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, was it a physical book or did you read it online?

Comment: At least 5 years ago maybe more, i read it online.

Comment: Was this a Japanese novel that has been adapted to manga? It sounds familiar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278517. No answers, but if it is the same story maybe this adds some details.

Comment: Yeah, i can tell its the same, but i read the novel idk if it have a manga. After all i read it when the novel was ongoing, to many years ago.

Comment: https://zetrotranslation.com/novel/the-case-in-which-streaming-in-another-world-led-to-the-creation-of-a-massive-yandere-following/01-im-a-streamer/ sounds vaguely similar, but he's reincarnated.